# Entropy of the multinomial distribution

Tags: multinomial-distribution, entropy

In my work I've found myself in the position of needing to calculate the entropy of the multinomial distribution:

$$\text{Multinomial}({\bf x};\; n,{\bf p})$$

I imagine it would be too much to expect a closed-form formula for this value, but what is the current standard method for efficiently calculating/approximating the entropy of a multinomial distribution?

Also my situation is for small $n$, so asymptotic approximations probably aren't the best for me unless they converge extremely quickly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok so I guess I should have done a bit of experimentation before posting this question.  I just assumed that since the Wikipedia article for the multinomial distribution didn't mention entropy, and since I couldn't find anything about it on google, that it was very difficult to compute.

Let
$${\bf X}\sim \text{Multinomial}(n,{\bf p})$$

The entropy for $\bf X$ is given by:
$$\text{H}({\bf X})=-\hspace{-4mm}\sum_{\substack{ {\bf x}\geq0\\\\\\ \sum_ix_i=n}}\frac{n!}{x_1!\cdots x_k!}p_1^{x_1}\cdots p_k^{x_k}\log\Big[\frac{n!}{x_1!\cdots x_k!}p_1^{x_1}\cdots p_k^{x_k}\Big].$$

Using the logarithm to break this up we obtain:
\begin{align}
\text{H}({\bf X}) &= -\log n! - \sum_{i=1}^k\log p_i\text{E}[X_i]+\sum_{i=1}^k\text{E}[\log X_i!]\notag\\
&=-\log n! - n\sum_{i=1}^kp_i\log p_i+\sum_{i=1}^k\text{E}[\log X_i!]\notag\\
&=-\log n! - n\sum_{i=1}^kp_i\log p_i+\sum_{i=1}^k\sum_{x_i=0}^n\binom{n}{x_i}p_i^{x_i}(1-p_i)^{n-x_i}\log x_i!.\notag
\end{align}

Thus we see that instead of summing over all distinct permutations of the partitions of $n$, which scales exponentially with both the size of $n$ and $k$, the derived form scales as $O((n+1)k)$, which is linear in both $n$ and $k$.

Comment: Two Q's: 1) Where did $E[X_i]$ come from? 2) From eq. (1) to (2), where did everything before log go?

Comment: @user13985 recall the definition of entropy is just $\text{E}[-\log(P(X))]$, so when the log breaks things up you just get a bunch of simpler expected values. The stuff before the log is just the probability distribution itself (multinomial pmf) and so it is just folded into the definition of expected value.

Comment: I see! I was trying to use this definition $H(X)=-\sum p(x) \log p(x)$. Instead, I should use this definition $H(X)=E[-\log(P(X))]$. I think that's the problem?

Comment: @user13985, well the former definition is canon. I provided you with the alternative definition to help make the point that it can be interpreted as an expected value, and to emphasize that it's a common pattern to look out for in the future, since once you recognize that an expression can be interpreted as an expected value, it may allow you to better see how to solve the problem.

Comment: Wait, both definitions will work? Now, I'm confused. I can only do it using alt. definition. :(

Comment: @user13985 I'm not sure I understand your concern, the definitions are equal to each other, you can switch back and forth between them at will. If you break things up with the log prior to interpreting it as an expected value, you can then at the next step just interpret each of the pieces as an expected value, they all have the appropriate form, i.e. $\sum_x p(x)f(x)$.

Comment: Still not sure how you got from eq. (1) to eq. (2). Can you write out some middle steps?

Comment: Actually nevermind, I think the intermediate step IS $H(X) = E [- \log (P(X))] $. That's how a sum in (1) becomes expectation in (2).

Comment: @Set May I ask how you figure out that scaling $\mathcal{O}((n+1)k)$? For example, if $k$ is small compared to $n$, then the scaling is supposed to be of order $\mathcal{O}(\ln n)$ which is smaller than your suggested order of magnitude.

Comment: @gatsu it's been a while since I derived this, but I think what I meant was that the original formulation will, in general, be intractable to compute because the number of terms you have to sum over grows exponentially with respect to $n$. While in the final expression, you just have to sum over $n$ terms.